# Public class multiple extends and implements

Tags: java, android, eclipse, multiple-inheritance

So... I use this public class right now and it works fine (MainActivity.java) For my tabs in my app. But I want to do something with the tabs and need to use buttons and textViews and other stuff.
But I cant because I need to use two extends and two implements for them both to work.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements TabListener
```

How it should look/work, how it need to look and work

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity, Activity implements TabListener, OnClickListener
```

Any fix or knowledge in how to fix this? (I use Android Eclipse)

Comment: You can't extends several classes directly. You can do `A extends B` and the `B extends C` if you have to. However, implementing multiple interfaces shouldn't pose any problems.

Comment: You can do A extends B and the B extends C
Could you do that with my example I don't really understand how and what you mean with that? Also does it work wit "implements" too?

Comment: `public class MATemp extends Actionbar {...}`, then `public class MainActivity extends MATemp implements TabListener, OnClickListener {...}`. If you want to make sure that MATemp won't be instantiated, make it abstract with `public abstract class MATemp ...`. This is basic Java, so you probably should go and learn about inheritance from a book or tutorial before going further.

Comment: All I have been doing is watching tutorials ^-^ Started coding about 5-6 days ago :p 
I think I got it so what your saying is that: 

`public abstract class MATemp extends ActionbarActivity
public class MainActivity extends MATemp implements TabListener, OnClickListener`

Comment: Yes, except **you can't do it in one go**. You have to do it separately, which is why I put them as separate in my examples.

Comment: `public abstract class MATemp extends ActionbarActivity                                 public class MainActivity extends MATemp implements TabListener, OnClickListener` Right?

Comment: As long as `MATemp` and `MainActivity` are 2 seperate classes, looks good.

Comment: Nop, cant get it working :/

Comment: Did you create 2 different classes, extending the appropriate classes? If yes, open another question, post your code and error message/reason why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html section "Abstract Classes Compared to Interfaces".

If you want to define behaviour that multiple classes can implement, the most common approach is to use an interface.

Answer (score 0):

Your `MainActivity` is a kind of `Activity`, but the activity is not an `ActionBar`.  It may *have* an `ActionBar` or make use of one, but it is not an `ActionBar`.  Therefore, trying to get the `MainActivity` class to extend `ActionBar` is the wrong concept.

I'm not sure what you want to do (I personally haven't tried using the `ActionBar` class directly).  If you just want your activity to do stuff with the action bar, just declare a variable of type `ActionBar`:

```
ActionBar actionBar;
```

and assign it to `getActionBar()` or `getSupportActionBar()` when you need it.  If you really want to *add* functionality to the `ActionBar` provided by Android, maybe you could define a class that extends `ActionBar`, but I don't know how you'd tell Android to use your new class for the action bar it sets up.  See [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html).

**EDIT:** After I posted this answer, the question was edited, so that your class now extends `ActionBarActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity, Activity implements TabListener, OnClickListener
```

That's different.  However, `ActionBarActivity` already extends `Activity`, therefore you don't need to put `Activity` in the above class definition.  It will automatically extend `Activity`.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, I do have all those things are you mentioning for my tabs. The problem is that I also need extends Activity and implements Tablistener. For a save button

Comment: @GoldToazt It looks like you changed the question after I answered it.